# eregi to preg_match replacement

Tags: regex, preg-match, eregi, ereg

I am converting an old PHP4-5 script to make it PHP 7 compatible.

I have the following line:

```
if ( eregi('^'.$_POST["category"],$r->id) ) $Category_List .= (' selected ');
```

Can I simply do this?

```
if ( preg_match('^'.$_POST["category"],$r->id) ) $Category_List .= (' selected ');
```

or do I need to do this?

```
if ( preg_match('"/^('.$_POST["category"],$r->id).')/"i' ) $Category_List .= (' selected ');
```

Comment: Do not forget the regex delimiters with preg_quote,`preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($_POST["category"], '/') . '/',$r->id)`

Comment: isn't my second example correct then @WiktorStribiżew? In the second example I have the '/' as regex delimiters and I have the ^ right after the first one to match the beginning of a string, and the 'i' flag after the last one to make it case insensitive... is it not correct the way I did it?

Comment: If you try you will see.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I realized I put the regex delimiter after the string instead of before, so I really meant to say this `if ( preg_match('"/^('.$_POST["category"].')/"i', $r->id )` - is this correct?

Comment: But you still need to make sure special chars are escaped, so use preg_quote.